# Powershell not returning value if empty

Tags: powershell

Using the following code

```
import-module activedirectory

$users = @("user1", "user2", "user3")
$results = @()

foreach($user in $users) {
    $properties = @{
        Name = (get-aduser -Identity $user).Name
        Manager = get-aduser (get-aduser -Identity $user -Properties manager).manager -properties displayName
        DirectReports = get-aduser (Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties directreports).directreports -properties displayName
    }
    $results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties | select Name, Manager, DirectReports
}

$results
```

Only user3 actually has direct reports, so it is printing his line 3 times.  But it doesn't print a line for user1 and user2.  How can I get it to print their lines, even if the DirectReports column is empty for them?

Comment: Add a test-case.  Assign your new-object to a variable, test for null.  `If ($Null -eq $Properties.DirectReports) { $Properties.DirectReports='' }` empty string example for displaying rather than `$Null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with the Manager and DirectReports lines, the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet not executed correctly, you use it three times, one for each property,
also, `get-aduser (Get-ADUser...).manager or directreports` may not be valid use for the identity parameter, as it use the manager as the identity, if you don't have aduser with the manager or directreports identity it will fail.

So I Suggest you to get the ADUser once, with the required properties and then use it like this,

Also the `$ADUser = $null` will force the reset of the variable so you will not get repeated lines for the same user.

```
$users = @("user1", "user2", "user3")
$results = @()

foreach($user in $users) {
    $ADUser = $null
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser $user -Properties Manager,DirectReports
    if ($ADUser) {
    $Row = "" | Select Name,Manager,DirectReports
    $Row.Name = $ADUser.Name
    $Row.Manager = $ADUser.Manager
    $Row.DirectReports = $ADUser.DirectReports
    $results += $Row
    }
}

$results
```